# How to update one file's column from another file's column in awk

Tags: awk

I have two files, the first file:

```
1 AA
2 BB
3 CC
4 DD
```

and the second file

```
15 AA
17 BB
20 CC
25 FF
```

File 1 should be updated and the expected output should looks like this:

```
15 AA
17 BB
20 CC
4 DD
```

I have tried this script from another post but it didn't work

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}a[$1]{print $2,a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

Comment: It is really not clear what should govern the replacement of these fields. The script you found will simply take the lines from `file2` whose first field exists in the second field from the first file, and print the second field and the field from the first field which they had in common.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `awk 'NR==FNR { a[$2] = $1; next } a[$2] { $1 = a[$2] } 1' file2 file1`

Comment: @triplee that would fail if a `$1` from file2 was `0` and has other issues. The test should be `$2 in a`, not `a[$2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next} $2 in a{$1=a[$2]} 1' file2 file1
15 AA
17 BB
20 CC
4 DD
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{f2[$2]=$0; next}
$2 in f2 {print f2[$2]; next}
1' file2 file1
```

Prints:

```
15 AA
17 BB
20 CC
4 DD
```